# What is the difference between being immutable and the fact that there can only be one instance of a Symbol?

Tags: ruby

I'm reading Eloquent Ruby, and am on Chapter 6 on Symbols. Some excerpts:

"There can only ever be one instance of any given symbol. If I mention :all twice in my code, it is always the same :all."

```
a = :all
b = :all
puts a.object_id, b.object_id  # same objects
```

"Another aspect of symbols that makes them so well suited to their chosen career is that symbols are immutable - once you create that :all symbol, it will be :all until the end of time (or at least until your Ruby interpreter exits)"

What is the difference between being immutable and the fact that there can only be one instance of you?

By the way, I would like to write the previous sentence more accurately: "What is the difference between a class being immutable and the fact that there can only be one instance of the class?" Is class the right word to insert there?

How would you even go about trying to mutate a symbol, they don't seem to hold values like other variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is fine; you're not sure of the common phrase used to describe a class with only one instance.  I'll explain that as I go along.

---

An object that is immutable cannot change through any operations done on it.  This means that any operation that would change a symbol would generate a new one instead.

```
:foo.object_id # 1520028
:foo.upcase.object_id # 70209716662240
:foo.capitalize.object_id # 70209719120060
```

You can certainly write objects that are immutable, or make them immutable (with some caveats) via `freeze`, but you can always create a new instance of them.

```
f = "foo"
f.freeze
f1 = "foo"
puts f.object_id == f1.object_id # false
```

An object that only ever has one instance of itself is considered to be a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

- If there's only one instance of it, then you only store it in memory once.
- If you attempt to create it, you only get the previously existing object back.

Answer (score 3):

Immutable means that an object cannot be changed. In Ruby, symbols are immutable. To make a symbol mutable, you have to perform type conversion to a string, which is mutable.

```
a = :mystring
a = a.to_s
=> "mystring"
```

For proof that a symbol is immutable, you can call the `frozen?` property on it.

```
a.frozen?
=> true
```

Note that symbols cannot be unfrozen unlike strings which have an `unfreeze` method.

For object ids

In Ruby, the `object_id` of an object is the same as the VALUE that represents the object on the C level. For most objects, this points to a location in memory where the object data is stored. This varies over time because it depends on where the system decided to allocate its memory.

Symbols have the same object id because they are meant to represent a SINGLE value.

To check this out, let's type to the console the same symbol multiple times.

```
:z.object_id
=> 636328

:z.object_id
=> 636328

:z.object_id
=> 636328
```

Now, let's try the same thing only with strings

```
"z".object_id
 => 21237740

"z".object_id
=> 24355380
```

As you can see, here we have two references to the string `z`, both of which are different objects. Thus, they have different object_ids.

This also means that symbols can save quite a bit of memory, especially if we are dealing with big data. Because symbols are the same object, it's faster to compare them then it is strings. Strings require comparing the values instead of the object ids.

Comment: You may have seen a now-deleted comment I posted on your answer. I argued that `frozen?` was not a good test of whether an object is immutable. I was wrong. Not only does it show that all `symbols`, `fixnums`, `true`, `false`, `nil` are immutable, but it also shows that mutable objects that have been frozen (which can't be unfrozen) are also immutable.

Comment: Appreciate the insights Cary Swoveland. I had no idea that if you froze strings, you couldn't unfreeze them again. Just checked it out myself in IRB

Comment: More generally, no frozen object can be thawed (see [Object#freeze](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-freeze)). [This](http://tmm1.net/ruby21-fstrings/) might be of interest.